# When you get the tracks from the global playlist from Itunes/AppLe Music with Applescript how do you get only filetracks

Tags: applescript, itunes

When you get the tracks from the global playlist from Itunes/Apple Music with Applescript how do you get only filetracks

e.g

I can do

```
return tracks of playlist 1
```

but that will return all tracks including those on the cloud, I only want the one that are actually stored on the harddrive

I see you can use a filter but how do I filter to only retrieve filetracks ?

Comment: I suspect that AppleScript is incapable of filtering by `class`, even if that is a declared property. For some reason `return tracks of playlist 1 whose class is file track` does not work. *Error -1731, Unknown object type.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71793299/942774) is almost right.

```
tell application "Music" to return file tracks of playlist 1
```

works for *most* instances of the AppleScript class `playlist`, but not for all of them, because the element `file tracks` is only declared in various sub-classes, but not in the `playlist` class itself.

For example, it does not work, if the playlist happens to be a `radio tuner playlist` or an `audio CD playlist`. They don't declare the `file tracks` element.

So before calling `file tracks of`, you should check the `class` property of the playlist to ensure your playlist object actually has a `file tracks` collection.

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "Music" to return file tracks of playlist 1
```